# Limit a program to use WiFi network card only

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, ethernet, windows-server-2016

I have one Ethernet card and one WiFi card on my windows server 2016 standard.
My server use Ethernet card to access internet and WiFi card is used to access a VPN network (for remote location).

Our office have seven locations. Five locations on same network that can be access using Ethernet card (Different IP and gateway)  and two locations using WiFi card (Different IP and gateway) that are based on VPN.

Now when i run an application (Attendance Management System - Bio Metric Devices Software) to sync data from remote locations. This software sync data from Ethernet card but not from WiFi card for VPN locations.

I set Ethernet card metric value 50 and WiFi card metric value 5 so server give priority to WiFi network.

But this is not working. I want to know that is there any way to limit one program to access specific network card for connectivity ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ForceBindIP should do exactly what you're after

Setup instructions [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/117890/how-to-force-an-application-to-use-a-specific-network-card/)

Comment: Software recommendations do not make good answers here, they are off topic, this should be a comment. It is a nice solution though.

Comment: @moac when no routing hardware information was supplied in the question, and the request isn’t not available As a part of the operating system I believe my comment is useful and definitely not worth a down vote and it’s the only way to do this, guess I’ll leave questions without answers in the future like this

Comment: @Moab thanks for your quick solution. Your provided software is working fine for me so i am marking your answer as solutions. Cheers.!!

Comment: @ShahidAmin Thanks for the reply, glad it helped 

Comment: Sorry i want to tag @SQLTemp :) and moac thanks for your clarification.

Comment: @ShahidAmin that was not my solution, but SQLTemp's.

Comment: @SQLTemp Can i bind IIS with specific ip ? e.g "C:\Program Files (x86)\ForceBindIP\ForceBindIP.exe" 192.168.0.32 "C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\inetmgr.exe"

Comment: @SQLTemp i did that with forcebind GUI.How i can set a program to always starts with a bind IP ? Suppose i bind an application with IP 192.168.0.32, I want that when ever i start windows this programs auto starts with this IP.

Answer (score 0):

In routed IP networks, a used interface is choosed by routing table. So check your routing table for destination IP network.

Comment: How exactly do you do this? Detailed answer would be nice. @lazna

Comment: By 'route' command in windows console