# (How) can I force a program to use only Ethernet, never WiFi?

Tags: windows-10, networking, router, vpn

I have a router, and behind it there is a second router with VPN firmware.

Basically, I want to use the non-VPN WiFi (of the non-VPN router) for most programs (gaming, most browsing, etc) and an Ethernet connection to the VPN router for a few others maybe just one browser, maybe also Thunderbird, etc, but not many). Both of these from a single laptop.

Can I do that using just Windows 10 (e.g the Windows Defender firewall)? If so, how? Or, do I need to ask for an app on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)?

---

[Update] I should have made it clearer - I want to be able to use both WiFi and Ethernet at the same time, with most programs on WiFi and a few on Ethernet

Comment: It seems like there should be a more elegant solution, but simply enabling/disabling the adapters could work (say, via script).

Comment: Usually you'd do this by address. In years of networking it's always been *addresses* that are routed, not programs. A good answer over at Apple.SE: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304172/how-to-make-different-apps-use-wifi-vs-ethernet

Comment: Though apparently you might be able to bind a program to a specific interface... https://superuser.com/questions/1517619/limit-a-program-to-use-wifi-network-card-only not sure if that works, but the answer is pretty sparse. From the linked page it seems like you end up with a whole slew of new shortcuts for your programs. `You will have to launch the program via this method every time you want to bind it to that network card.`

Comment: @Anaksunaman sorry, I was not clear. I want to be able to use both WiFi and Ethernet at the same time, so I can't disable the adapters. I will update the question (+1)

Comment: @Mokubai while I agree with you )+1), ExpressVPN manages it somehow. and I can say that some programs must only use the VPN. My problem is that if VPN drops, I don't want taose programs to have any traffic, but ExpressVPN only allows the option of stopping all traffic if my VPN drops, not just some, which seriously messes with gaming.

Comment: You can do so via Windows Defender Firewall, and it would likely be easier to configure allow rules for the programs you want to access the VPN set to the ethernet adapter, then a final rule blocking all traffic on the ethernet adapter, combined with block rules for the VPN programs, blocking their access to the WiFi adapter, keeping in mind firewall rules are hierarchical.

Comment: Then, why not post an answer? Fro a browser only solution, I wonder if I could use a specific port, use that as proxy in the browser & set it to accept only Ethernet connections in the firewall.